# Change language of whole react-native app

Tags: function, react-native, translate, i18next

My app in react-native has 2 languages: english and french. I've done a i18n.js file and 2 "translation.js" files for english and french. It's working great (i've tried it setting french on my phone, english on the emulator).

Now, I want to make a button in the app's settings to change the language of the entire app for the user but I don't know what function call and how to create this.

Can you help me ? 
Thanks a lot for your time and help.

my i18n.js file;

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import detector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { reactI18nextModule } from "react-i18next";
import { NativeModules, Platform } from "react-native";

import en from "../public/locales/en/translation.js";
import fr from "../public/locales/fr/translation.js";

// the translations
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: en
  },
  fr: {
    translation: fr
  }
};
const locale =
  Platform.OS === "ios"
    ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale
    : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;

i18n.locale = locale;

i18n
  .use(detector)
  .use(reactI18nextModule) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: locale.substring(0, 2),
    fallbackLng: "en", // use en if detected lng is not available

    keySeparator: ".", // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

And I'd like to change the language from my Settings.js file :

```
<SettingsList.Item
              // icon={<Image style={styles.image} source={require('../../assets/images/icon_vol-mute.png')}/>}
              title={i18n.t("settings.action.languages")}
              hasNavArrow={false}
              switchState={this.state.activeSwitch === 3}
              switchOnValueChange={this.switchThree}
              hasSwitch={true}
              onPress={() => Alert.alert("French / English")}
            />
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using `i18next`

you can `i18next.changeLanguage` use to change your language

```
export const changeLanguage = (languageKey) => {
i18next.changeLanguage(lng, callback) // -> returns a Promise
}
```

```
import { changeLanguage } from 'services/translation';

<Button onPress={() => {changeLanguage(languageKey)}} />
```

But i recommended change to use [react-native-localization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-localization) instead of `i18next` by `simply in implementation` and `native performance`

### How to use `react-native-localization`?

#### Installation

```
yarn add react-native-localization --save

#react-native >= 0.60
cd ios && pod install && cd ..

#react-native < 0.60
react-native link react-native-localization
```

#### Declare your translations

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';
import english from './en.js'
import french from './fr.js'
import korean from './kr.js'

const strings = new LocalizedStrings({
 en: english,
 fr: french,
 kr: korean,
});
```

with `en.js`, `fr.js`, `kr.js` are the files contain your translations in `key` `value` format.

eg: content of `fr.js`

```
export default {
ok: 'D'accord',
no: 'non'
}
```

You can also use `json` file type for declaration.

#### usage

```
import strings from 'services/translation';

<Text style={styles.title}>
  {strings.ok}
</Text>
```

#### Change languages

write a function to change your app language and use it in every where you want.

```
const strings = new LocalizedStrings({
 en: english,
 fr: french,
 kr: korean,
});


export const changeLanguage = (languageKey) => {
strings.setLanguage(languageKey)
}
```

```
import { changeLanguage } from 'services/translation'


<Button onPress={() => {changeLanguage(languageKey)}} />
```

> **Notes:** Do not declare key same at default methods like `setLanguage`

##### *See more about `react-native-localization` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-localization?activeTab=readme)*

Comment: What a rich answer ! Thank you for taking the time to be that precise ! 
Can I ask what is 'LanguageKey' when I try the solution with i18next it shows error : 'can't find variable 'LanguageKey' (should I replace it by 'fr' or 'en') ?
I'd like to make it work this way in a first step, but I think I will consider using the other solution you provided. 
Again, thank you.

Comment: of course, it exactly is [language-code](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=language+code&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). You can use `en`, `fr` or any valid language codes

Comment: Perfect, it works !! Thank you so much for your help and time !

Comment: I've also did (by myself) what you explained, @Wing but I've found out that bottom navigation from react native paper and also the one from react navigation use lazy loading for the pages... So they are not translated! ‍ Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In `react-native` with `i18n-js`, you can change the language by setting the locale property of the i18n object with the language code of your choice.

```
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import 'moment/locale/ar';
// Change the language to Arabic
i18n.locale = 'ar';
// Change the language to English
i18n.locale = 'en';
//etc
```